# Cannot install RStudio addins on my Windows laptop from behind proxy

Tags: r, proxy, rstudio, devtools

My session info (basically it's Microsoft R Open 3.4.1, RStudio 1.0.153, Windows 10 64 bit)

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils    
[5] datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RevoUtilsMath_10.0.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] httr_1.3.1       compiler_3.4.1  
 [3] R6_2.2.0         RevoUtils_10.0.6
 [5] tools_3.4.1      withr_2.0.0     
 [7] curl_2.6         memoise_1.1.0   
 [9] git2r_0.19.0     digest_0.6.12   
[11] devtools_1.13.3
```

I'm trying to install some [RStudio addins](https://rstudio.github.io/rstudioaddins/) without success. Whatever addin I try to install, the recommended procedure of using `devtools::install_github` (see [Installation](https://rstudio.github.io/rstudioaddins/#installation)) fails with the same error message:

```
> devtools::install_github("benmarwick/wordcountaddin", type = "source", dependencies = TRUE)
Installation failed: Failure when receiving data from the peer
> devtools::install_github("rstudio/addinexamples", type = "source")
Installation failed: Failure when receiving data from the peer
```

I work behind a company proxy. I am able to install R packages from CRAN without problems:

```
> install.packages("devtools")
Installing package into ....
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2017-09-01/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/devtools_1.13.3.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 443758 bytes (433 KB)
downloaded 433 KB

package ‘devtools’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
....
```

How can I install RStudio addins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install from github using proxy settings with httr package:

```
library(httr)
with_config(use_proxy(url='proxy url', port = port_number, 
                      username="username", password="yourpass"), 
            devtools::install_github('github/directory'))
```

Comment: you should correct `port_number` to `port =  port_number`. It will make the answer more readable and I'll accept it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.